# MIPS processor - why sub cause overflow and slt isn't?

Tags: assembly, mips

I was doing some exercises for my "Electronic Calculators" Exam and i found this question that was a bit tricky for me.

> Referring, if necessary, to the green card, consider the two instructions of the MIPS sub and slt processor. Assume that both provide for the use of the ALU to subtract the two source operands, in particular the slt in order to compare them. Note how in the green card it is expected that the diver can cause the exception for overflow [cf. note (1)], while this is not present in the case of the slt. How can you explain it? The quality of the justification given affects the evaluation of the response.

I was trying to figure out the answer, but i'm not sure that it's correct. I think that the difference is on the purpose of the instruction, in fact if in the sub I have to store a real "value" in the register i need that number to be correct. On the other hand in the slt I just need to understand if the number is higher or lower that the other one... is that correct? You guys have a better answer?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That question seems to have been written by a non-native english speaker, or (badly) translated from another language?  I can't quite follow the grammar of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree — the `slt` only needs to answer greater or less between its operands, which can be done without running into overflow.

But we can go into further detail.

First, let's note that `sub` needs to signal overflow (by throwing an exception), and so some extra logic beyond mere 32-bit subtraction operation alone is used to detect that.

Thus, we might assume that `slt` also has some extra logic beyond mere 32-bit subtraction (it is also different from `sub` in that it captures a 0 or 1 result rather than the subtraction result directly).

This extra logic for `sub` could be that it does subtraction to a 33-bit result — and if the 33'd bit is different from the 32'd bit, then the 32-bit answer would be lossy in magnitude, i.e. overflow.

Or this extra logic for `sub` could be that it does 32-bit subtraction, and that it compares the signs of the inputs with the sign of the result.  If the sign of the inputs are the same it cannot overflow, but if the sign of the inputs are different, and the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the minuend (the first operand), then overflow occurred.

For `slt`, one could detect overflow the way that `sub` does (compute the 1 vs. 0 result given a 33-bit answer or the comparison of 3 signs approach), but there is a very simple way (a) to detect if overflow is possible, and (b) side step (or bypass the sub operation) with an easy answer, when overflow would be possible.

So, what I would do would be per the following table:

```
 minuend   subtrahend    can           slt
(source1)  (source2)   overflow?      result    
----------------------------------------------------------------
  pos         pos         No       sign of subtraction operation
  pos         neg         Yes      0 (sign of minuend), ignore subtraction
  neg         pos         Yes      1 (sign of minuend), ignore subtraction
  neg         neg         No       sign of subtraction operation
```

In summary, if the signs of the inputs differ then the `slt` result is the sign of the minuend, and otherwise the `slt` result is the sign of the subtraction (which cannot overflow as the signs of the inputs are the same).

Since we have at least 3 implementation strategies that can obtain an answer without any risk of the incorrectness caused by overflow, there is no need for `slt` to cause an exception.

(A silly instruction set architecture could indeed define an overflow exception for this instruction and throw exceptions for the same cases as `sub` — this would be like capturing the sign of the subtraction result for the answer for `slt`, while also detecting subtraction overflow and excepting in those cases.)

Comment: Perhaps interesting to compare ISAs with FLAGS, like x86.  `cmp` sets flags like `sub` (including the signed-Overflow and negative (Sign-bit) flags, and x86's signed conditions like `jl` being SF≠ OF. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc.  (x86 sub / cmp don't trap on signed-overflow, since it has a FLAGS register; only MIPS has a separate `subu` instruction.)

Comment: indirectly related: x86 has [`ucomisd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ucomisd) for an FP compare that won't raise an exception even if used with signalling NaN with FP exceptions unmasked.  And also [`comisd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comisd) that will.  But there's no fault-suppressing `usubsd`, only plain `subsd`.  Slightly similar reason: you sometimes want comparisons to work even if the equivalent subtraction would fault.  Because you need to find out stuff about the inputs, that's the whole point of a comparison.  (But in other ways it's quite different from signed-overflow)