# Can overflow occur when a positive number is subtracted from a positive number resulting in a negative number?

Tags: overflow, mips, subtraction

I am working with the mips assembly language but am confused on the overflow aspect of arithmetic here.

Say I am subtracting 25 from 20 and end up with -5. Would this result in an overflow?

I understand that with addition if you add 2 positive numbers or 2 negative numbers and the output is the opposite sign then there is overflow but am lost when it comes to subtraction.

Comment: See also [MIPS processor - why sub cause overflow and slt isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061872/mips-processor-why-sub-cause-overflow-and-slt-isnt)

Answer (score 0):

Find the examples at the extreme, let's do it in 8 bits signed to make it simple but the same principles holds in 32 bits

- minuend: the smallest possible positive (non-negative) number, 0 and
- subtrahend: the largest possible number, 127

When we do 0 - 127, the answer is -127 and that indeed fits in 8 bits signed.  There is a borrow.  In any processor the effect of the borrow is to propagate 1's though out the upper bits, making it a negative number of the proper magnitude.

Different processors set flags differently based on this borrow, MIPS doesn't have flags, while x86 will set flags to indicate borrow, and other processors will set the flags to indicate carry.

In 8 bit signed numbers:

- minuend: the smallest possible positive (non-negative) number, 0 and
- subtrahend: the largest possible number, -128

When we do 0 - -128, the answer should be 128, but that cannot be represented in 8 bit signed format, so this is the example of overflow.  0 - -127 = 127 and that can be represented, so no overflow there.

---

If we do it in 8 bits unsigned, your example of 25-20 = -5, but -5 cannot be represented in an unsigned format, so this is indeed overflow (or modular arithmetic, if you like that).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, as the 32-bit representation of -5 is `FFFFFFFB`.

Long answer: Depends on what you mean by "overflow".

- There's signed overflow, which is when you cross the `7FFFFFFF-80000000` boundary.
- And there's unsigned overflow where you cross the `FFFFFFFF-00000000` boundary.

For signed arithmetic, signed overflow is undeniably a bad thing (and is considered undefined behavior in C and other languages). However, unsigned overflow is not necessarily a problem. Usually it is, but many procedures rely on it to work.

For example, imagine you have a "frame timer" variable, i.e. a 32-bit counter variable that increments by 1 during an interrupt service routine. This interrupt is tied to a real-time clock running at 60 hertz, so every 1/60th of a second the variable's value increases by 1.

Now, this variable *will* overflow eventually. But do we really care? No. It just wraps around back to zero again. For our purposes, it's fine, since we really don't need to know that accurately how long our program has been running since it began. We probably have events that occur every `n` ticks of the timer, but we can just use a bitmask for that. Effectively in this case we're using unsigned overflow to say "if this value equals `FFFFFFFF` and we're about to add 1 to it, reset it to zero instead." Which thanks to overflow we can easily implement without any additional condition checking.

The reason I bring this up is so that you understand that overflow is not always a bad thing, if it's the unsigned variety. It depends entirely on what your data is intended to represent (which is something you can't explain even to a C compiler.)